# Is configuring Database mail considered as a security threat?

Tags: sql-server

Is configuring Database mail and sending email using sp_send_dbmail considered a security threat?

Comment: I can't think of one reason that would make it a security threat.

Comment: There stands [in this document](http://tinyurl.com/7rzssd9) that: _Because some system procedures interact with the operating system or execute code outside of the normal SQL Server permissions, they can constitute a security risk. System stored procedures such as xp_cmdshell or sp_send_dbmail are off by default and should remain disabled unless there is a reason to use them._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring DB mail is not a security risk. DB mail is disabled by default, This way, if you don't need DB mail, you are reducing the surface area of your SQL server. If you need to use DB mail, you can enable and start using it.

Xp_cmdshell is a bit more powerful and is better left disabled.

Answer (score 2):

In a vacuum, any activated feature is an additional attack vector (or, additional "surface area" for the system). That said, I've never read or heard of any attack or exploit using DB Mail.

Comment: Yeah, but a really *good* exploit wouldn't be detected.  I have to live with that hanging over my head every day.

Comment: Fair enough, but if it's never happened anywhere... I'd hate to not get email alerts of server problems due to fearing I'd be the first. The lack of incidents involving the feature makes the risk low enough in my mind to justify using it. Keeping the business moving is the higher priority in this case IMO.

Comment: "Fair enough, but if it's never happened anywhere..." But if it's a really *good* exploit, you wouldn't know it's never happened. The exploits we *know* about are the clumsy ones; the clumsy ones leave footprints.

Comment: I disagree with that. There are major non-profits (OWASP for example) that deliberately publish security exposures for the sake of putting white hats on to proper defense. All the major security providers do this, and it's a boon for an individual white hat to publish an exploit and how to protect from it before anyone else does. The idea that there is some secret knowledge that we have no hope of protecting ourselves from is not realistic. If you never walk out of the door of your house you'll reduce the chances of being run over by a bus, but there is value in going out of the door.